# How update record in a table based on a button click in Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm currently designing an application using Apex 20.1. When the user clicks a button I want to update the record in a table.

I changed the button action to define by dynamic action and the dynamic action is to execute PL/SQL:

```
UPDATE COSTCODETOCATEGORY
    SET   
        ACTIVE = 'N'
    WHERE 
        TROPOS_COSTCODE = :P21_TROPOS_COSTCODE;
```

Unfortunately no changes are made to the table. Does anyone have ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Have you put ```P21_TROPOS_COSTCODE``` in the "items to submit" property of your dynamic action ?

Answer (score 0):

Why dynamic action and not **process**?

Button, when pressed, by default submits.

Create the process and put

```
UPDATE COSTCODETOCATEGORY SET    
  ACTIVE = 'N' 
  WHERE TROPOS_COSTCODE = :P21_TROPOS_COSTCODE;
```

and that should *just work*, with no additional actions.